# Unable to find browscap.ini file in wamp\bin\php

Tags: php, wamp

I am new to it , trying to learn php using wamp and some video tutorial from youtube.

I can't find the browscap.ini file in `wamp\bin\php`. Where can it be located?

If I have to download this file, where can I find the correct file? And  what are the changes I have to make in the `php.ini` file after downloading the browscap.ini?

Answer (score 1):

Allmost you need to know is available in the online PHP manual. Strange that is it not!

[The Browsercap page in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) click on the link in the Notes section to download browsercap.ini, then place it in `C:/wamp/bin/php/phpx.y.z/extras/`

In `php.ini` you add a line like this ( replace x.y.z with your actual folder name )

```
browscap = "C:/wamp/bin/php/phpx.y.z/extras/browsercap.ini"
```

Remember to do this to the php.ini in the apache folder as well as the php.ini in the phpx.y.z folder, so you can use it from a browser and PHP CLI

Restart Apache once this is done to make your chnages avalable to Apache